# How Auto Implemented Get property returns specific data member

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

First of all I want to inform all you guys that I already spent 3 days reading material and watching tutorial and still having hard time understanding this concept! Please help me understand how Auto-implemented property of a class decides what data member to return when you have multiple data members. Following is a code snipped that extracts simple data out of SQL (a table with 3 columns; Id(int-which is PK),Name(nvarchar) and IsSelected(bit))server using entity framework and generates radio buttons. when you select each of radio button and hit the submit it will tell you which *Department* (ID), you have selected.

My questions is , there are 2 other data members within this context, how that Auto Implemented Get method *SelectedDepartment* figures to take the *Id* field ?

Also the *Id* Data type in the SQL server is int, however the data type which is defined for the *SelectedDepartment* is string ! how deos it work

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Model (Company.cs) ;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace RadioButton.Models
{
    public class Company
    {
        public string SelectedDepartment { get; set; }
        public List<Department> Departments
        {
            get
            {
                SampleContext db = new SampleContext();
                return db.Departments.ToList();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Controller ;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RadioButton.Models;

namespace RadioButton.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private SampleContext db = new SampleContext();

        //
        // GET: /Home/
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Company company = new Company();
            return View(company);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public string Index(Company company)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(company.SelectedDepartment))
            {
                return "You didn't select any";
            }
            else
            {
                return "you have selected " + company.SelectedDepartment;
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            Department department = db.Departments.Find(id);
            if (department == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(department);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Home/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Department department)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Departments.Add(department);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(department);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            Department department = db.Departments.Find(id);
            if (department == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(department);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Home/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(Department department)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(department).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(department);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            Department department = db.Departments.Find(id);
            if (department == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(department);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Home/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Department department = db.Departments.Find(id);
            db.Departments.Remove(department);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

View ;

```
@model RadioButton.Models.Company

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach(var department in Model.Departments)
    {
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, department.Id) @department.Name
    }
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Comment: If you're asking what I _think_ you're asking, `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, department.Id)` is the operative statement here.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thank you , so does it mean that the *SelectedDepartment* property once instantiated holds all members within it self ? and then we can use any member we want in the view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties are just value accessors; they're dumb, which is to say, there's no magic here. The most basic property is basically just this code:

```
private string someProperty;
public string SomeProperty
{
    get { return someProperty; }
    set { someProperty = value; }
}
```

All auto-implemented properties in C# do is simply convert `public string SomeProperty { get; set; }` into that code above behind the scenes. There's no access to any other property on the class, and the property has no knowledge of any other property on the class, nor does it care.

`Html.RadioButtonFor` takes a property (via an expression) and a value, and uses that to construct a radio input. Initially, the actual value of your `SelectedDepartment` property is null, but `Html.RadioButtonFor` is not looking at its value, but rather the value you're feeding it in the second parameter as the `value` attribute of the HTML input. In this case, you're using the `Id` property, but it hardly matters. The `name` value of the HTML input, meanwhile, gets set to "SelectedDepartment", because that's the property you told it to bind to.

Now, when you post back, the value of the *input* is sent as the value for `SelectedDepartment`. It doesn't know or care that the value originally came from the `Id` property. You could just as easily do:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, "foo")
```

And the value of `SelectedDepartment` on postback would be "foo". The point is that there's no direct correlation to where the value originally came from, just that it was the value of the HTML input at the time of post.

Comment: I do appreciate your detail answer ! thank you very much

Comment: Now, what if I want to include other data members ! let's say Name along with Id! I tried @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, department.Id , department.Name) which it won't accept !

Comment: The second parameter is just a value type. You can't include multiple properties because, again, just one value will ever be posted back for that input. You *could* concatenate the values (i.e., `department.Id.ToString() + department.Name`), but I don't think that's what you're looking for here.

Comment: Basically, this just boils down to simple HTML. There's no strong-link between your class and the HTML page. Razor simply renders the HTML which then gets sent to the client. The client posts back some data which is then interpreted by the modelbinder.